# Handling the paste event in a UIViewController

Tags: iphone

I would like to handle the paste event in my UIViewController for my attached UITextView, so that if the pasted data is text or html it should paste the data in as normal and as it already does, but if it is something else like a image or pdf or anything, I would like to store the data locally in another way and not paste it into the UITextView (as it can not do this).

How would I go around doing this? In the only example I can find from Apple, they know the type of the data they paste. Even getting my "-(void)paste:(id)sender" method in my controller to get called when there is a paste event in my UITextView escapes me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method [canReadObjectForClasses:options:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPasteboard/canReadObjectForClasses%3aoptions%3a) to test for something without actually retrieving the value.

For example, testing for strings:

```
NSArray *classes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSString class]];
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionary];

if ([[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard] canReadObjectForClasses:classes options:options]) {
    NSLog(@"yup, there is a string in here");
}
```

**Update:**

You're checking for all objects in the paste board this way, just add any class that you expect on the array.

```
NSArray *classes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSURL class], [NSString class], nil];
```

Use the [UIResponderStandardEditActions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html) protocol to implement the paste method.

Comment: Would it not be better to check for all UTIs in the pasteboard? How do I catch the paste method call?